# Firefox saves password but chrome not saving password for login form

Tags: php, html

For my login form firefox saves but chrome not prompting the "save password" box. I have tried by adding autocomplete="on" but it is not working. Can any one suggest me the answer. I didn't want to use any extention.My code is given below.

```
<form spellcheck="false" autocomplete="on" id="login-form" action="/user/login/do-login" method="post">
                <div class="separator-bar"></div>
                <div class="credentials-container">
                    <div class="username-container">
                        <div class="label">Email/Username: </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input class="wx-input" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->escape(App_Api_User::ARG_USERNAME)?>" value="<?php if(isset($this->username)) {echo $this->username;}?>" spellcheck="false"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="password-container">
                        <div class="label">password: </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input class="wx-input" type="password" name="<?php echo $this->escape(App_Api_User::ARG_PASSWORD)?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="separator-bar bottom"></div>
                <div class="forgot-password-container">
                    <div class="text">forgot password: </div>
                    <div class="password-page button"><a class="loginForgotPassword" href="#">CLICK HERE</a></div>
                </div>

                <div class="submit-container">
                    <input class="login button disabled" type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" />
                </div>
                <div id="infoMessageContainer">

                </div>

                <div class="general-error"></div>

            </form>

$('body').on('click', '.submit-container .login', function(e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }else{
                var self = this;
                self.submit();
            }
        });

 _success: function()
    {
        window.location.href = '/user';      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made lots of changes and then finally works with below block of code.
Hope it will help someone. You need to submit form with this code.

```
        var winNav = window.navigator,
        isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");
        var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        //Use below if statement, if you want to run only in chrome 
        if(isChrome || isIOSChrome){
            $('#login-form').submit(function () {
                if(-1 !== this.action.indexOf('/login')) {
                    var jForm = $(this);
                    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                        if (data.success == true) {
                           jForm[0].action = '/user';
                           jForm.submit();
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

All browsers use heuristics for knowing when to save passwords. I'm familiar with Firefox and Chrome. The heuristic they use seems to be:

- The form must have a password field
- The text input just before the password field is assumed to be the user name
- Only those two input fields are saved. Firefox then prompts you that
  it can remember your changed password when you fill out a form with two password fields.

Here is a list of things that I typically see break these algorithms:

- Sites that use autocomplete=off (specifically requesting that
  browsers not remember passwords)
- Separating login into multiple pages where the user name is entered on one page and the password is entered on the next.
- Using Javascript to copy the contents of these fields into hidden
  fields in a hidden form and then submitting the hidden form rather
  than the visible form
- Requiring more than two fields to be filled out such as 
  User name, SSN, and password
  Username, password, and PIN
- Changing the names of the username and    password fields
  periodically (causes firefox to no longer be able to    fill in the
  password, even when it is remembered).

Comment: My password save problem is with chrome browser. I have verified all the above rules but it is not working for me. Please Any other solution.

Comment: I have the same problem, someone please help.

Comment: @dave guru, I have posted the answer for this question.